# If I have 1000 different Infopath forms do I need to create 1000 Form Library in SharePoint2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath

If I have 1000 different Infopath forms do I need to create 1000 Form Library in SharePoint2010 to collect the data and trigger workflows?

I don't want to save the user submitted data into a list and is there a way to group all the Form Libraries? Or I am doing it completely wrong???

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it via single Form Library itself. Deploy the forms as content type or as Administrator Approved form template.

You can then add the Infopath form content type specific to your forms to the single form library.

http://www.lcbridge.nl/vision/infopath.htm

Comment: Dear Madhur,

Thanks. When you have *different* infopath forms in 1 "Form Library" all the fields will have different names and conflicting names... how do you manage that?

Comment: i dont think theres a technical way to manage that... we ended up prefix'ing the columns with a 3 char identifier